# Problems with a loop in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a problem with using a loop to assign an id within a relationship between numbers. I have 6 columns with numbers and I would like each number that has direct or indirect relations to have the same ID to assign them to one group, as shown here:

| number | number1 | number2 | number3 | number4 | number5 | number6 | GroupId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11111111111 | 11111111111 | 22222222222 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 1 |
| 33333333333 | NULL | 22222222222 | 77777777777 | NULL | NULL | NULL | 1 |
| 77777777777 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 1 |
| 77777777777 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 1 |
| 22222222222 | 88888888888 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 1 |
| 44444444444 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 2 |
| 55555555555 | 00000000000 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 3 |
| 55555555555 | 00000000000 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 3 |
| 00000000000 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 3 |

I tried to use standard joins and subqueries, unfortunately without effect. same for the loop. my every approach to creating loops returns me stupidity the same with joins. I expected the result as above and it returns me a completely different Group id

Fitr

```
CREATE TABLE #PrzypisanieKlientow 
(
    Id INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
    Pesel1 NVARCHAR(11),
    Pesel2 NVARCHAR(11),
    Pesel3 NVARCHAR(11),
    Pesel4 NVARCHAR(11),
    Pesel5 NVARCHAR(11),
    Pesel6 NVARCHAR(11),
    GroupId INT
);

INSERT INTO #PrzypisanieKlientow (Pesel1, Pesel2, Pesel3, Pesel4, Pesel5, Pesel6)
VALUES
    ('11111111111', '11111111111', '22222222222', NULL, NULL, NULL),
    ('33333333333', NULL, '22222222222', '77777777777', NULL, NULL),
    ('77777777777', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
    ('77777777777', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
    ('22222222222', '88888888888', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
    ('44444444444', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
    ('55555555555', '00000000000', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
    ('55555555555', '00000000000', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
    ('00000000000', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

UPDATE PK
SET GroupId = CTE.GroupId
FROM #PrzypisanieKlientow PK
JOIN (
    SELECT Pesel, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Pesel) AS GroupId
    FROM (
        SELECT Pesel1 AS Pesel FROM #PrzypisanieKlientow WHERE Pesel1 IS NOT NULL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT Pesel2 AS Pesel FROM #PrzypisanieKlientow WHERE Pesel2 IS NOT NULL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT Pesel3 AS Pesel FROM #PrzypisanieKlientow WHERE Pesel3 IS NOT NULL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT Pesel4 AS Pesel FROM #PrzypisanieKlientow WHERE Pesel4 IS NOT NULL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT Pesel5 AS Pesel FROM #PrzypisanieKlientow WHERE Pesel5 IS NOT NULL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT Pesel6 AS Pesel FROM #PrzypisanieKlientow WHERE Pesel6 IS NOT NULL
    ) AS CTE
) CTE
ON PK.Pesel1 = CTE.Pesel OR PK.Pesel2 = CTE.Pesel OR PK.Pesel3 = CTE.Pesel OR PK.Pesel4 = CTE.Pesel OR PK.Pesel5 = CTE.Pesel OR PK.Pesel6 = CTE.Pesel;
```

Results:

| number | number1 | number2 | number3 | number4 | number5 | number6 | GroupId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11111111111 | 11111111111 | 22222222222 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 2 |
| 33333333333 | NULL | 22222222222 | 77777777777 | NULL | NULL | NULL | 3 |
| 77777777777 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 7 |
| 77777777777 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 7 |
| 22222222222 | 88888888888 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 8 |
| 44444444444 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 5 |
| 55555555555 | 00000000000 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 6 |
| 55555555555 | 00000000000 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 6 |
| 00000000000 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 1 |

Comment: Shouldn't '44444444444' be in its own group?

Comment: I agree, thanks for noticing

Answer (score 0):

You're close.  You're updating the GroupId with `DENSE_RANK()` but you want to assign the same GroupId to Pesel with direct or indirect relations. You should be using the `DENSE_RANK()` function along with a Common Table Expression (CTE) to create unique groups and then update the main table.

This should do it, though this is untested:

```
WITH Relationships AS (
    SELECT 
        Pesel1 AS Pesel,
        CASE WHEN Pesel2 IS NOT NULL THEN Pesel2
             WHEN Pesel3 IS NOT NULL THEN Pesel3
             WHEN Pesel4 IS NOT NULL THEN Pesel4
             WHEN Pesel5 IS NOT NULL THEN Pesel5
             WHEN Pesel6 IS NOT NULL THEN Pesel6
        END AS RelatedPesel
    FROM #PrzypisanieKlientow
    WHERE Pesel1 IS NOT NULL
), Grouped AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT Pesel, Pesel AS RootPesel
    FROM Relationships
    UNION ALL
    SELECT r.Pesel, g.RootPesel
    FROM Relationships r
    JOIN Grouped g ON r.RelatedPesel = g.Pesel
), RootGroups AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT Pesel, RootPesel, 
           DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY RootPesel) AS GroupId
    FROM Grouped
)
UPDATE PK
SET PK.GroupId = RG.GroupId
FROM #PrzypisanieKlientow PK
JOIN RootGroups RG ON PK.Pesel1 = RG.Pesel OR PK.Pesel2 = RG.Pesel OR PK.Pesel3 = RG.Pesel OR PK.Pesel4 = RG.Pesel OR PK.Pesel5 = RG.Pesel OR PK.Pesel6 = RG.Pesel;

SELECT * FROM #PrzypisanieKlientow;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but something is still wrong. GroupId still assigned incorrectly in row order 2,3,7,7,8,5,6,1,1

Comment: Ahh right, I updated the answer.

Comment: when I used the code, the error "Invalid column name 'RootRank'" appeared, so in the "SELECT" above I added RootBank and it works but it still shows incorrect data. Now in turn assigns 4,8,15,13,16,10,11,12,3

Comment: OK, here's another way... I updated it to base the relationships between Pesel values using CTE

Comment: Thank you for the fix, there is currently a problem with GorupId because it does not detect it, but I do not see that there is an error in the code